# Display error message for empty data in XTemplate

Tags: extjs

ExtJS XTemplate lets you use `.` in a `for` tag to loop through all the records in the store:

```
tpl: new Ext.XTemplate(
    '<tpl for=".">',
    '<div>{thing}</div>',
    '</tpl>'),
```

I'd like to render a message instead if the set is empty (i.e. if the for loop is never entered). I've set `allowEmptyStore: true`.

How can I use an if statement to determine whether the store is empty. I've tried `if(".")`, `if(Ext.empty(.)`, and `if(Ext.empty(this.myStore))`. I'm guessing this is a fairly common thing to do with templates. What's the magic syntax I'm missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution lies in the magic `values` variable. The following will be triggered if the underlying store is empty:

```
'<tpl if="!(values && values.length)">',
...
'</tpl>',
```